# Getting y values back from spline fit

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, spline

I used the MATLAB curve fitting tool to do a spline smoothing fit and created a function from it.  How can I access the Y fit values so I can output them to a file?  Seems I am only seeing the x values, and all of the coefs from fitresult.  Here is the matlab code.  Thanks!

```
function [fitresult, gof] = createFit(Freq, AmplNew)
%CREATEFIT(FREQ,AMPLNEW)
%  Create a fit.
%
%  Data for 'untitled fit 1' fit:
%      X Input : Freq
%      Y Output: AmplNew
%  Output:
%      fitresult : a fit object representing the fit.
%      gof : structure with goodness-of fit info.
%

%% Fit: 'untitled fit 1'.
[xData, yData] = prepareCurveData( Freq, AmplNew );

% Set up fittype and options.
ft = fittype( 'smoothingspline' );
opts = fitoptions( 'Method', 'SmoothingSpline' );
opts.SmoothingParam = 0.998;

% Fit model to data.
[fitresult, gof] = fit( xData, yData, ft, opts );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [**`feval`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/feval.html):

```
y = feval(fitresult,x);
```

or just use

```
y = fitresult(x);
```

Comment: You could also simply do fitresult(x).